# Objective-C: Prevent UIView from inheriting behaviors upon attachment to second UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Say I have two UIViews `UIViewWithGravity` and `UIViewWithoutGravity`.  `UIViewWithGravity` is added to the gravity behavior:

```
    [self.gravity addItem:UIViewWithGravity];
```

`UIViewWithoutGravity` is not.  At this point, `UIViewWithGravity` falls off the screen, `UIViewWithoutGravity` stays put.  So far, so good.

Now, I tie the two together using a `UIAttachmentBehavior`.  Something like:

```
- (void)attachViews {
    self.attachment = [[UIAttachmentBehavior alloc] initWithItem:[self.UIViewWithGravity viewWithTag:GRAVITY_TAG]
                                                  attachedToItem:[self.UIViewWithoutGravity viewWithTag:NO_GRAVITY_TAG]];

    [self.animator addBehavior:self.attachViews];
}
```

`UIViewWithGravity` now drags `UIViewWithoutGravity` off the screen.

How can I attach these views together such that `UIViewWithGravity` swings freely from `UIViewWithoutGravity`, but does not cause `UIViewWithoutGravity` to be pulled down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach the view without gravity to something that doesn't move (a fixed anchor).